# Is Google Firestore get() request for a non existing document, charged?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I recently realized that even if a Firestore `query` doesn't match any document, I will still be charged for 1 read.

In my case, there could be lots of queries for non-existing docs, and I want to avoid this cost.

In my case, the client already has (or can generate locally) the relevant `document Id` beforehand, but the client still doesn't know if this document exists or not. 
So instead of querying and receiving the doc, I can do `get(docId)`

**Question**: Does the Firestore charge for replying `error` to a `get()` request of the non-existing document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation on Firestore pricing](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/pricing) says:

> **Minimum charge for queries**
>
> There is a minimum charge of one document read for each query that you
>   perform, even if the query returns no results.

So it sounds like you will be charged.  The important thing to realize is that the indexes the Firestore uses to manage your documents do take time and space to maintain, so if you make use of an index, it's reasonable to expect that it's going cost money because of resources consumed.

Comment: Thank you, I understand. I saw this document earlier as well, but i didn't realize that get() is a query(). ( It's better if the pricing document mention it for get(), like they mention it for query() )

Comment: You can think of document `get()` as a query with a filter on only document ID equality.

Answer (score 2):

A `get()` call for a document that requires the server to read data is charged as a document read. Since the server needs to check whether the document exists, that is a charged read operation (as far as i know).

Comment: Thank you, i understand. ( If it was mentioned in clearly in pricing document, it can help to design the DB better )