# Pay per for each get method in a firebase function?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Hey im trying to figuring out if i have a firebase function and inside 4 get methods like this

```
export default functions
  .runWith(runtimeOpts)
  .firestore.document("ParentComment/{commentID}")
  .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    try {
      const db = admin.firestore();
      const { videoID, author, text,videoowner } = snap.data() || {};
      const ref = db.doc(`videos/${videoID}`);
      const videouid = await db.doc(`videos/${videoID}`).get();

      const userSnap = await db.doc(`meinprofilsettings/${author}`).get();
      const { commentID } = context.params;
  
      const recoveringuser1 = await db.doc(`Recovering/${videoowner}`).get();
      const recoveringuser2 = await db.doc(`Recovering/${author}`).get();
…
```

do i have to pay for each get method?
or does it count as 1 read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) elements for Firestore in play here are:

- Document Reads: as the name implies, you will be charged for each **document** that your code causes to be read from the database on the server. Since you are reading 4 individual documents, there are 4 charged document reads
- Network Bandwidth: you may also be charged for the bandwidth that is consumed for transferring the data. If the Cloud Function and Firestore are in the same region, this charge is waved.

For more on this, I recommend reading the [Firestore pricing](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/pricing) page in the documentation.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the nice answer. One question left . What if the use for example one get just to check if the doc exists . Let say if(recoveringuser1.exists)   and it return false. So the doc does not exists means I don't read anything. Do I have to pay for get() if there was no result?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59700648/is-google-firestore-get-request-for-a-non-existing-document-charged